# Why do doubles not correctly parse from my String[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, double

I am trying to parse double values from a single dimension String array. When I attempt to do this, the doubles always parse as 0.0, never as the correct value. Why is this the case?

Code:

**Parser Method:** (Ignore integer parser, this one works fine when given an integer)

```
NumReturn numberParser(int cIndex) { // current index of array where num is
        NumReturn nri;
        NumReturn nrd;
        try {
        nri = new NumReturn(Integer.parseInt(Lexer.token[cIndex]), cIndex++, 'i');
        System.out.println(nri.value + " ");
        return nri;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException intExcep) {

          }
        try {
        nrd = new NumReturn(Double.parseDouble((Lexer.token[cIndex])), cIndex++, 'd');
        System.out.println(nrd.dvalue + " ");
        return nrd;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException doubExcep) {
            doubExcep.printStackTrace();
          }
        return null;


    }
```

**NumReturn Class:**

```
package jsmash;

public class NumReturn {
    int value;
    double dvalue;
    int pointerLocation;
    char type;
    NumReturn(int value, int pointerLocation, char type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.pointerLocation = pointerLocation;
        this.type = type;
    }
    NumReturn(double dvalue, int pointerLocation, char type) {
        this.dvalue = value;
        this.pointerLocation = pointerLocation;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

**String array which I am trying to parse from:**

```
static String[] token = new String[100];
token[0] = "129.4"; // I call my parser on this element of the array
token[1] = "+";
token[2] = "332.78"; // I call my parser on this element of the array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem here is a simple typo. In the second `NumReturn` constructor (the one with the double parameter), you currently have the following:

```
this.dvalue = value;
```

This will assign `this.dvalue` to the initial value of `this.value`, which is 0. It is ignoring the constructor parameter entirely. What you actually want is this:

```
this.dvalue = dvalue;
              ^
```

Comment: AHA! Lol. That was 2 hours of my life I'll never get back. Thank you so much. Sorry for such a silly mistake.

Comment: I suppose I should just delete this question? Since it is not really going to help anyone in the future? @andersschuller

Comment: Why would you think this wouldn't help anyone in the future?

Comment: @LewBloch because it wasn't a programming mistake, it was a typo.